# Is it possible to connect a Gamecube Controller to a 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

I play a lot of SSB4, and I have gotten used to using the 3DS to play. But, is there a way I can connect a Gamecube (or other type of controller) to my 3DS, and play using that instead? I want to practice with a real controller (and prevent my Circle Pad from dying).

Comment: Lol anything is possible regarding stuff like this

Answer (score 3):

It *is* possible. It just depends on how comfortable you are with actual hardware modding. [Here's an article with a how-to video.](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2014/10/modder_shows_how_to_play_the_3ds_with_a_gamecube_controller)

[Link to the YouTube video in article.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seAI9W9SYjo) How-to links, hardware requirements, and source code are all found in the video description. The method looks extremely cheap (12$). The real issue is just being comfortable with the process.

Also, some other [modders.](http://3dscapture.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1729)

On removeability:

> It will have a circuit board attached to the back, you can unplug everything and use it like a regular 3DS, or plug in the Arduino and start playing with gc controller.

Comment: Does it effect online play in anyway (not as in controller wise, but legal stuff), and can it be safely/easily removed for safer transport?

Comment: From the modder: https://docs.google.com/document/d/165fPdv2UORf3wDJl_VQ9BlPpjIOSYkWMLWaV2yxCCVI/mobilebasic?pli=1